# Why is there no Gauge plugin version for Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, intellij

I have been using Eclipse for building my automation framework. Recently I wanted to use gauge in my framework. But while trying to install the plugin I noticed that the version number of Gauge for Eclipse is 0.0.3(not been updated for last 1 year) whereas for other IDE the version number is 0.9.4.
Isn't it a huge drawback the gauge doesn't support one of the most widely use IDE.
My question is - 
Does this mean that I will have to use IntelliJ to use latest version of Gauge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now Gauge has plugins with official support for Intellij IDEA, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code.

Unfortunately, we don't have enough users or resources to maintain the Eclipse plugin.

Note: I am part of the Gauge core team.

Comment: The tone of your answer suggests that you are affiliated with Gauge - please edit your answer to indicate your affiliation so you aren't in violation of our spam policy.

Comment: Gauge is a great framework in my personal opinion as I have used myself. If there was a eclipse plugin I believe gauge would have much more reach.

Comment: Thanks! Newer versions of Gauge supports the Language Server Protocol which in turn is now supported on the latest versions of Eclipse. Once we finish some work on supporting it completely on Java it should start working again on Eclipse. But that will be sometime later this year.

Answer (score 1):

No, each "product" has their on version numbers.  So each plugin/package being separate from the standard IDE means it has a different number scheme.  You need to check the release notes for the plugin/package and check compatibility with Eclipse versions to see which versions are supported with the plugin/package.